# NSFileManager rename file using "moveItemAtURL:" with a name contains path separator like "foo/bar.extension"

Tags: macos, cocoa

This feels weird, my code goes as simple as

```
// something like "foo/bar"
NSString *correctFileName = seriesDict[seriesNumber];
if (correctFileName.length > 0)
{
    // So I'll have a fileName like "foo/bar.extension" which looks like a directory and a file in it...
    NSString *pathExtension = [filePath pathExtension];
    NSString *correctFilePath = [[[filePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
                                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:correctFileName]
                                    stringByAppendingPathExtension:pathExtension];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:filePath toPath:correctFilePath error:&error];

    // And NSFileManager can not treat it as a legal fileName, kind of expected...   
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Rename file at %@ failed, error: %@", filePath, error);
    }
}
```

Seems it's ok to rename my file to "foo/bar.extension" in Finder, like this

[image]

there might be a solution to do that in code.

If anybody could shred in some light, it'll be highly appreciated.

Comment: Finder lets you do that, but it isn't really putting a directory separator in the filename, it's just showing you one. If you `ls` the directory with that file, you'll see the real name is "foo:bar.mkv". Directory separators are not valid in filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` in Finder is converted to a `:`. `/` is invalid in POSIX-style paths, while `:` is invalid in HFS-style paths, so macOS maps those two characters to each other.

The technically correct way would be to create a `CFURL` using `CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPathRelativeToBase` specifying `kCFURLHFSPathStyle` as the path style, and resolving against a base URL you've already created. You'd then copy the path of the full URL using `CFURLCopyFileSystemPath`.

Pragmatically speaking though, you can simply do a string replace between `/` and `:`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand.